# JavaScript Image object inside "class"

Tags: javascript, image, class

Good afternoon,
I am playing a little in javascript and I have a "class" of this form:

```
var Card = function(url,c){
            ...
            this.img = new Image();
            this.widthCurr = 0;
            this.heightCurr = 0;
            this.img.onload = this.imageLoaded()
            this.img.src = this.url;
        };
```

and a method defined as

```
Card.prototype = {
            imageLoaded : function(){
                //my goal is to initialize this.widthCurr and this.heightCurr
                console.log(this.img.width);
            },

            ...
        };
```

Basically my goal is to initialize widthCurr and heightCurr with actual width and height of img, when the img is loaded. I created new object and console.log command in imageLoaded keeps saying "0" so at that time, image is not loaded. I tried a few modifications, but no one seemed to work. Am I missing something important? How or where should I set these values?

Answer (score 3):

```
        this.img.onload = this.imageLoaded()
```

You just called the function, and assigned its result to `this.img.onload`.

Instead, you need to assign the function itself, and you need to bind `this`:

```
        this.img.onload = this.imageLoaded.bind(this)
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, I can probably see the difference, but when I change the code, the body of imageLoaded function seems not to be executed at all.